# jQuery Mobile - changePage and select menu not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, refresh, select-menu

This is my first time with jQuery Mobile and I'm actually using it from a WP theme I got. I understand that this might be theme related but I just want to make sure.

So, it is a Wordpress jQuery Mobile theme, you plug it and it works a treat. The thing is, I've converted the Wordpress menu from an UL to a SELECT.

I have then added some jQuery to fire the select on change by getting the value of the selected option. That works, I get the loading thinggy and then the page changes with my desired effect.

But I can't get the Select menu to show the current selected item. It always reverts to the first one.

I have used:

```
$('#main_menu').selectmenu("refresh");
$('#main_menu').selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

But nothing...

You can have a look at the site here: http://avatarblog.fl1hosting.com/ and look at the source.

You will see that my mobile event are all before the jQuery Mobile include, which doesn't make much sense to me, but if I put them afterwards, nothing works.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set which option to show in the select menu. Try this,

```
$("#main_menu")[0].selectedIndex = 2; // this will select the 3rd in the menu list
$("#main_menu").selectmenu("refresh");
```

You can add the following script your header.php:

```
$(document)
.unbind("pageshow.initMenuBtn")
.bind("pageshow.initMenuBtn", 
    function() {
        $.mobile.activePage = $("div.ui-page-active");
        $("#main_menu", $.mobile.activePage)
          .unbind("change")
          .bind("change", function() {
                var page = $(this).val();
                $.mobile.changePage(page);
            });

        var selectedIndex = 0;
        $("#main_menu>option", $.mobile.activePage).each(function(index) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("current-menu-item")) {
                selectedIndex = index;
            }
        });
        $("#main_menu", $.mobile.activePage)[0].selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
        $("#main_menu", $.mobile.activePage).selectmenu("refresh");
    });
```

Comment: Hi jay. I'm afraid that didn't work. Also I don't completely understand... Wouldn't that code display always the 3rd item in the list? What I'm trying to do is to display the current page item, so if I click on About us, the select shows About us and so on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, it won't work just like that. please check my updates in my post above. in the first code, i am just giving you an idea why your call to $("#main_menu").selectmenu("refresh"); didn't work as you expect. it's actually because the selected value in your is always the first option.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm afraid that didn't work either. This is a Wordpress site so I'm adding all the code on header.php, which is included on all templates. The select list is dynamically generated from the database and when an option is clicked, jQuery gets the value of the option and fires a changePage to that value.

Comment: ok. then please check the updated code above. based on the generated HTML, you can actually get the selectedIndex by the option element class attribute.

Comment: btw, the above code can be placed in your header.php file and it will already handle which menu should be displayed in all your pages.

Comment: Thanks Jay. It seems it starting to do something but it isn't right just yet. Correct me if I'm wrong, because I'm new to jQuery Mobile, but from what I have read around the internet, `$(document)` doesn't work and `$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){` should be used instead? Not sure really, I've tried placing that code on different locations and it doesn't seem to work 100%

Comment: I have left the code in the header so you can have a look and test the behavior yourself, if that's alright. Try going to the different pages several times and you'll see the strange behavior. If I'm on a page and the current item isn't displaying correctly and then I refresh the page, it then gets updated to the correct item. Thanks

Comment: from what site did you get that information? $(document) always works. also, do you know that as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is already deprecated (http://api.jquery.com/live/). in jquery mobile, pages are cached by default, that is why we have $.mobile.activePage to indicate the active div with data-role=page. we use the "pageshow" event if we want to perform action after the transition animation has completed. for list of events and their description, please check http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html.

Comment: please check updated code above and remove your $('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){}) code in your page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Sorry, I got confused when reading. It was using `$(document).bind('pageinit')` over `$(document).ready()` ;) Unfortunately your code still doesn't work. It seems to be doing the same thing as before: Select a menu item, the page loads, HOME shows as the current page, but if you refresh the page menu item gets updated. I'm going a bit crazy here! Thanks for everything Jay

Comment: Just realised the theme was adding its own version of jQuery, so I removed that. Also it wasn't using the latest version of jQuery Mobile so I removed it and added the latest one... but it all went even worse! Not sure what's going on here! Help please! :)

Comment: hello elmediano. i think it's a totally different layout now. so what's the issue? your menu seemed to be displayed in tabs now, and it looks good. what do you mean it went even worse?

Comment: Hi Jay. Sorry I changed it back to the desktop version as the Mobile one only loads when looking at it on a mobile device. I've just changed it so it shows the Mobile one in case you could have a quick look :)

What I meant by it went worse is that, when I put the latest version of jQuery Mobile and clicked on a menu item, it wouldn't even fire the changePage event correctly. What it would do is change the URL and page title correctly but the content would stay the same. I don't know I have looked everywhere and can't find an answer :(

Comment: for some weird reason, i don't know why the $.mobile.activePage is not updated. try the modified code above instead. let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Absolute legend! That worked Jay! Thanks a million times, really appreciate it :)